systemd-journal-gatewayd how to use --since and --until
Journalctrl has the --since and --until flags to limit the returned entries by date time.
According to the documentation of systemd-journal-gatewayd it's possible so send a GET request with the Range Header set:
Range: entries=cursor[[:num_skip]:num_entries]

Unfortunately, there is no further documentation as to how the cursor string can be set to achieve what I want.
In the code the RequestMeta suggests it's possible to set since and until, and the request_parse_range_time method seems to parse for just that.
Before I go deeper into the code, I wanted to quickly ask if somebody knows how to use the API to filter using since and until?
Any answer however short will be greatly appreciated.

The feature is not yet released as of version 255, it's merged on the main branch though, and might be part of the next release.
